# Using if(boolean==true) in actionPerformed

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I currently have a class for an ATM project. In my actionPerformed, I have 4 buttons (twenty, fifty, hundred and other). Lets stick with depositing money into account. I would like to differ chequing deposit from savings but have them in the same java file.

In my attribute I have

```
 private triggerChecker checker;
```

that decides if user is going for chequing(true boolean or saving(false boolean).

The code below will be showing my actionPerformed method

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
  //Loop through the keypad array to see if any of the buttons were pressed 
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      if (e.getSource() == keypad[i])
      {
         //Edit the input display
         cardID = cardID + i;
         display.setText("\n\n\tPlease enter amount of money:" + "\n\t" +cardID);
      }
   }

   if(e.getSource() == keypad[11]){
        cardID = "";
        display.setText("\n\n\tPlease enter amount of money:" + "\n\t" +cardID);
  }

  if(checker.getCheck() == true){
  if (e.getSource() == twenty)
  {
      display.setText(feature.DepositTOC(20.0));
      display.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,18));
      display.setVisible(true);

  }

  if (e.getSource() == fifty)
  {
      display.setText(feature.DepositTOC(50.0));
      display.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,18));
      display.setVisible(true);

  }

  if (e.getSource() == hundred)
  {
      display.setText(account.toString());
      display.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,20));
      display.setVisible(true);
  }

  if (e.getSource() == other)
  {
      cardID = "";
      display.setText("\n\n\tPlease enter amount of money:" + "\n\t" +cardID);
  }
  if(e.getSource() == keypad[12]){
      double num = Double.parseDouble(cardID);
      display.setText(feature.DepositTOC(num));
      display.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,18));
      display.setVisible(true);

  }
  }
  if(checker.getCheck() == false){
      if (e.getSource() == twenty)
      {
          display.setText(feature.DepositTOS(20.0));
          display.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,18));
          display.setVisible(true);

      }

      if (e.getSource() == fifty)
      {
          display.setText(feature.DepositTOS(50.0));
          display.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,18));
          display.setVisible(true);

      }

      if (e.getSource() == hundred)
      {
          display.setText(account.toString());
          display.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,20));
          display.setVisible(true);
      }

      if (e.getSource() == other)
      {
          cardID = "";
          display.setText("\n\n\tPlease enter amount of money:" + "\n\t" +cardID);
      }
      if(e.getSource() == keypad[12]){
          double num = Double.parseDouble(cardID);
          display.setText(feature.DepositTOS(num));
          display.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,18));
          display.setVisible(true);

      }}
     }
```

I have a feeling that I am not able to if(boolean == true) in actionPerformed. If you have ideas, please let me know as I am willing to work with tips and help and not planning someone to write a whole function for me. Thanks

checker class

```
public class triggerChecker {
private boolean checkW, checkD, checkWC, checkWS, checkDC, checkDS;

public triggerChecker(){
    checkW = false;
    checkD = false;
    checkWC = false;
    checkWS = false;
    checkDC = false;
    checkDS = false;
}

public void setCheckW(boolean s){
    checkW = s;
}
public void setCheckD(boolean s){
    checkD = s;
}
public void setCheckWC(boolean s){
    checkWC = s;
}
public void setCheckWS(boolean s){
    checkWS = s;
}
public void setCheckDC(boolean s){
    checkDC = s;
}
public void setCheckDS(boolean s){
    checkDS = s;
}


public boolean getCheckW(){
    return checkW;
}
public boolean getCheckD(){
    return checkD;
}
public boolean getCheckWC(){
    return checkWC;
}
public boolean getCheckWS(){
    return checkWS;
}
public boolean getCheckDC(){
    return checkDC;
}
public boolean getCheckDS(){
    return checkDS;
}

}
```

Comment: You never need to write `someBoolean == true` - `someBoolean` is equivalent (similarly `!someBoolean` is equivalent to `someBoolean == false`)

Comment: you dont need to do if(checker.getCheck() == true){ use instead if(checker.getCheck()){

Comment: Yeah but that won't help my problem. Will it?

Comment: *"I have a feeling that I am not able to `if(boolean == true)` in actionPerformed"* .. you have the "feeling"?

Comment: Do you getting an error?

Comment: I am not getting an error. My issue is I am using the same buttons twice in the actionPerformed but i would like the same button to do two different functions depends on condition such as `if(boolean == true)`

Comment: what is  getCheck() rerturns ?

Comment: I posted an answer below, but as an aside you should probably change `display` to a label with "Please enter amount of money:" and a text field. It's sort of odd to have to add that string back to the text field every time.

Comment: the reason i have `display` is because i am working on atm simulator and the `display` acts like a "screen"

Comment: @RaghuKNair getCheck returns true

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you can't access or use a boolean inside actionPerformed. The only thing you have to watch for is actionPerformed can be called by your user at times you don't expect, so make sure your boolean is initialized at all times that the user could perform the action you're listening on.